# how can I get xdebug to run in Windows

Tags: php, windows-7, xdebug

I apologize if I am not following protocol with this question; I realize it has been asked. However, I have yet to see an answer (that works)

I am trying to get xdebug working on a Windows 7 box.
Whatever build I try (and I have tried more 5 to this point), I get this message when I run `php -m` : `Failed loading C:\PHP5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-[compile + build].dll`

I have used the "wizard" (it doesn't provide much information) and it is the only module that doesn't work.

Comment: If you have not found a working answer, you should still provide a list of the usefully looking ones you've tried so far an explain briefly why they didn't work for you. That should keep your question in context to the related questions here on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Make XDebug works can be a little trick. But, after move through all challenges, you will see the benefits of quickly find bugs and quickly fix them.

First of all, you need to find out which is the version for your environment. It is tight related with PHP version you are running and XDebug page is the place to go to figure it out. 
The XDebug [wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) helps you to get the Xdebug module compiled to fit your environment.

If you copy the output of the following command:

```
php -i
```

inside the text box and hit the button "Analyse my phpinfo() output" as showed below:

[image]

You will see a report about the XDebug version you need. Most of times, the link to download it is available as showed below. If the link do not show, your version should have no compatibility with Xdebug

[image]

After follow the instruction gave by wizard page, the output of the command:

php -m

should be something like the image below:

[image]

Xdebug load successfully on [Zend Modules] group. Of course, it is not enough to make it work. But will be enough to you move forward. You told us, you used the wizard. If the steps above was the same you follow tell us what is the wizard output as a comment.